# Change MFC Menu to show all items instead of arrows?

Tags: mfc, menubar

Have an MFC application that uses one of the various styles available that has a `CMFCMenuBar` and toolbar.  For the `CMFCMenuBar` it only shows the items used, otherwise the double-down arrows have to be clicked to see the rest of the items.  How do I set it up so it's just all items all the time, without the arrows having to be used?

TIA!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on how the menu is created and initialized. Look for the following code in `CMainFrame` class:

```
CList<UINT, UINT> lstBasicCommands;
lstBasicCommands.AddTail(ID_FILE_NEW);
lstBasicCommands.AddTail(ID_FILE_OPEN);
...
CMFCToolBar::SetBasicCommands(lstBasicCommands);
```

If you find it, then remove the call to `SetBasicCommands`

Or keep `SetBasicCommands`, and also add all the commands to `lstBasicCommands`

Comment: This was it, for some reason the `CMFCMenuBar::SetShowAllCommands(TRUE)` didn't do anything (even when added after the `SetBasicCommands()`).

Answer (score -1):

Try using [`CMFCMenuBar::SetShowAllCommands`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cmfcmenubar-class?view=vs-2019#setshowallcommands) method.

Answer (score -1):

According to Microsoft, you should call

```
CMFCMenuBar::SetShowAllCommands(TRUE);
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cmfcmenubar-class?view=vs-2019#setshowallcommands